# Template for news module (database) in Kohana 3

Tags: php, mysql, database, kohana-3

I'm creating a news module for a site. But I do not want to create it from scratch.
Is there somewhere better practice to create tables for a news module?

I find http://www.dmxzone.com/go?4114 , but this example is very simple.

Can somebody advise?

bind to the framework's no need, I need tables from database.

Comment: realy depends on the "framework" you're working on ... please tell us more about it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how this guy is donig it, [Light weight blog module for kohana 3.0](https://github.com/kerkness/shindig), essentialy is the same thing ... istead of blog posts you'll call it news posts ...